# Android method parametre as array

Tags: java, android, arrays

```
public void setFont(String font_type, TextView[] fontArray)
{
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/" + font_type);

    for (int i = 0; i < fontArray.length; i++){
        fontArray.setTypeface(face);
    }
}
```

I want to add different textviews to different typeface. i could not find out how to implement foreach loop correctly.

Comment: Not clear!! can you elaborate more?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question. You need to access each element of the font array--maybe brushing up on some Java basics would be a good idea. Also, `for (TextView textView : textViews)` would make more sense than calling it `fontArray`, since it's not an array of fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the index in the loop:

```
fontArray[i].setTypeface(face);
         ^^^
      add this
```

...or use a "for each" (as you wanted):

```
for (TextView tv : fontArray)
    tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like any other Java array, you can iterate over its elements using a `for`-loop

```
for(TextView tv: fontArray) {
    tv.setTypeface(face);
}
```

See [Java: Array with loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687310/java-array-with-loop) for another example.

Note, the name `fontArray` is a bit misleading... You could rename it to `textViews` or something more appropriate...