# How do I use array to print out my values when i exit my program?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class DvdRental1 {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\r\n");
    static  DecimalFormat fmt=new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   


        String [] movies = new String[10];

        movies[0] = "DRAG ME TO HELL";
        movies[1]  = "PARANORMAL ACTIVITY";
        movies[2] =  "SHUTTER";
        movies[3] = "P.S I LOVE YOU";
        movies[4]  = "500 DAYS OF SUMMER";
        movies[5] = "THE NOTE BOOK";
        movies[6] = "2012";
        movies[7] = "THE DAY AFTER TOMORROW";
        movies[8] = "GAMER";


        showmainmenu();
    } // END OF MAIN

    private static void showmainmenu()
    {
        int perday;
        int  mainmenu;
        System.out.println("Welcome to TP DVD Rental Service");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("---DVD RENTAL SYSTEM---");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println("(1) Rent a DVD");
        System.out.println("(2) Exit");
        System.out.print("Please select your choice(1-2):");
        mainmenu= input.nextInt();



        if(mainmenu ==1 )
        {
            showmenu();             
        }
        else if (mainmenu == 2)
        {
            goExit();
            System.out.println("You have exited");          
        } 
        else 
              System.out.println("Please key in 1,2");
     }
}
```

This is my first time using `Java`. I have another question whether this is the right way to make the program run this way, as will the `showMenu()` method i am using will it cause to program to run endlessly ? Thank you so much. As i have most of my content using methods to do a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Make the array an instance variable, declared outside of any method. In other words, have this:

```
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\r\n");
static  DecimalFormat fmt=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String[] movies = new String[10];
```

You can initialize it either outside of any method as an instance variable as follows:

```
String movies[] = new String[] { "DRAG ME TO HELL", "PARANORMAL ACTIVITY",
        "SHUTTER", "P.S I LOVE YOU", ... };
```

Or you can just add the elements to the array inside `mainmenu()` as you are right now.

Then you can access it in `showmainmenu()` as well as in `goExit()` and loop through it, printing each entry just before doing `System.exit()` or whatever you do at the end of `goExit();`. You can do the latter (printing of the `movies` array) quite simply like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<movies.length;i++) {
    System.out.println(movies[i]);
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass a reference to the array as an argument to the various methods.

Answer (score 0):

Either pass movies as a parameter into showmainmenu(), and then in turn pass it onto goExit() or make it a global variable, in which case you can print it wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, you could make the following:

```
String [] movies = new String[10];
```

A ***global*** variable, so you can reference it from anywhere in the class:

```
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\r\n");
static  DecimalFormat fmt=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String [] movies = new String[10];//add here
```

Your second option is to pass the array to the `showmainmenu()` method.  It would look as so:

```
    showmainmenu(movies);
} // END OF MAIN

private static void showmainmenu(String [] movies)
{
    //rest of code
```

Finally, you in order to print this you must loop through the array and print each value:

```
    else if (mainmenu == 2)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<movies.length; i++){
            System.out.println(movies[i]);
        }
        goExit();
        System.out.println("You have exited");          
    }
```

[Read more about loops over arrays here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687310/java-array-with-loop)

> I have another question whether this is the right way to make the
>   program run this way, as will the showMenu() method i am using will it
>   cause to program to run endlessly ?

Yes, I would recommend a [do-while loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html):

```
private static void showmainmenu()
{
    int perday;
    int  mainmenu;
    System.out.println("Welcome to TP DVD Rental Service");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("---DVD RENTAL SYSTEM---");
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    do{
        System.out.println("(1) Rent a DVD");
        System.out.println("(2) Exit");
        System.out.print("Please select your choice(1-2):");
        mainmenu= input.nextInt();
        //code
        else if (mainmenu == 2)
        {
            goExit();
            System.out.println("You have exited");       
            break;//exits do-while   
        } 
        //code
    }while(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you can define each movies collection seperatelly  as global variable like :

```
    static String[] thrillerMovies = new String[] {"2012","THE DAY AFTER TOMORROW","GAMER"};
    static String[] loveMovies = new String[] {"P.S I LOVE YOU","500 DAYS OF SUMMER","THE NOTEBOOK"};
    static String[] horrerMovies = new String[] {"DRAG ME TO HELL","PARANORMAL ACTIVITY","SHUTTER"};
```

and define a method like below to show submenus :

```
private static void showSubmenu(String SubMenu,String[] movies) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println( SubMenu + "MOVIE SELECTIONS");
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        for(int i=0;i<movies.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("<" +(i+1)+"> " + movies[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("<4> Back to Main Menu");
        System.out.println("------------------------");

        System.out.print("Please select desired movie <1-3>:");

    }
```

You can print the choices by calling the above method in your `if` like

```
if (menu == 1) {
   showSubmenu("HORROR", horrerMovies);
```

-

```
else if (menu == 2) {
   showSubmenu("LOVE", loveMovies);
```

-

```
else if (menu == 3) {
    showSubmenu("THRILLER", thrillerMovies);
```

Similarly you can do the same in case of submenu choices if you wish. @Mohammad S. And @Martin Dinov already mentioned some points there.