# If a string ends with any value of an array Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an array

```
String[] Array = {"+", "-", "*", "/"}
```

and an EditText string

```
operation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.operation);
```

So, I have a button where I want to add an if statement like:

```
    Button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    if(operation.getText().toString().endsWith(Array.toString())){
                        prinln("Example"); }
                }
            });
```

I don't know how to make this right. How to write the if statements where the String ends with any value of array and make it work

Comment: I tried to debug if(operation.getText().toString().endsWith(Arrays.toString(Array))). But it's not working also

Comment: you need to iterate over the array and check each array element individually.

Comment: I have to do like : if (string.endsWith(Array[1]) || string.endsWith(Array[2])? I thought about it, but isn't there any more complicated and shorter way?

Comment: That is not iterating. You need a loop.

Comment: Ok, I think I got the point, i'll try it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Array with loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687310/java-array-with-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your array, this will take each of the string in the array and check if your String ends with the String 's' from the array

```
for (String s: Array) {
        //Do your stuff here
        if(yourString.endsWith(s)){
            println(example);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*If you really don't want to use a loop*, **you can save array values as keys and your desired answers as values** in a map.
And then **use the map** directly.

```
HashMap<char, String>operandMap = new HashMap<char,String>(); 
operandMap.put('+',"Addition");
operandMap.put('-',"Subtraction");
operandMap.put('*',"Multiplication");
operandMap.put('/',"Division");
operandMap.put('%',"Modulus");
println(operandMap.get(operation.getText().toString().charAt(operation.getText().toString().length-1)));
```